# Capturing load event for images dynamically changing their source

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am changing src for image dynamically and want to capture on load event for that image. Is there a way I can do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several years ago, I discovered that the onload event was not reliable in some browsers (I don't remember which ones) when setting `.src` for the second time.  As such, I settled for replacing the image object.  I would create a new image object, set the onload handler, set the `.src` value and then when it loads, insert it into the page in place of the existing image.

When creating an image from scratch in javascript, you do this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    // put your onload code here
};
img.src = "xxx.jpg"
```

If you just want to change the `.src` of an image, you just find the DOM object in the page and set it's `.src` property.

```
var img = document.getElementById("myImage");
img.src = "xxx.jpg";
```

If you want to try to capture the onload event when resetting the `.src` (what I had reliability problems with a couple years ago, you would do this:

```
var img = document.getElementById("myImage");
img.onload = function() {
    // your code here
};
img.src = "xxx.jpg";
```

If you want to load a new image and replace an existing one with it when it loads, you would do this:

```
function replaceImg(oldImage, newSrc) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        var parent = oldImage.parentNode;
        parent.insertBefore(img, oldImage);
        parent.removeChild(oldImage);
        // put any other code you want here when the 
        // replacement image is loaded and in place
    };
    img.src = newSrc;
}
```

And, you would call this like this:

```
<img id="myImage" src="yyy.jpg">


var oldImage = document.getElementById("myImage");
replaceImg(oldImage, "xxx.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// create image object
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function () { 
    // do stuff 

    $('#myimageelementid').prop('src', image.src); // set the element in the DOM with this image
}


image.src = "image.jpg"; // will trigger onload when loaded
```